# Setup a Webhooks

Tags: php, wordpress, post, webhooks

I would like to install a webhook so that when a user is filling a form on our website, some information are sent to another website.

The website is on Wordpress, but the form is integrated in a PHP template.

Apparently, some webhooks should already be setup, but I am not sure where. I am pretty new with PHP.

For confidential reasons, I removed the actual URL and wrote "URL" instead. Also English is not my first language, please fogive me for some misspelled words.

So the code for form code is as follow:

```
<div class='gf_browser_gecko gform_wrapper' id='gform_wrapper_1' >
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  id='formulaireintervention'  action='URL/themes/grafity/valide-formulaire.php' name='formulaireintervention' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        
        <div class='gform_body'><ul id='gform_fields_1' class='gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below'>
        
        <li id='field_1_15'  class='gfield gsection field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible' ><h2 class='gsection_title'>
        
        Informations sur le nid</h2></li>
        
        <li id='field_1_24'  class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible' ><label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_24' ><?php  esc_html_e('Nombre de nids', 'netbee-translate'); ?><span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label><div class='ginput_container ginput_container_select'>
          <select name='nombredenids' id='input_1_24'  class='medium gfield_select'   aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" >3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7" >7</option>
            <option value="8" >8</option>
            <option value="9" >9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
          </select>
      </div></li>
      <div class='gform_footer top_label'> <input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_1' class='gform_button button' value='<?php esc_attr_e('Soumettre', 'netbee-translate'); ?>' style="background-color:#f7941f;border:1px solid #2f2f2f;color:#2f2f2f;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;"/> <?php esc_html_e('Vous serez ensuite rediriger vers un récapitulatif de votre demande', 'netbee-translate'); ?> </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'> if(typeof gf_global == 'undefined') var gf_global = {"gf_currency_config":{"name":"Dollar US","symbol_left":"$","symbol_right":"","symbol_padding":"","thousand_separator":",","decimal_separator":".","decimals":2},"base_url":"https:\/\/URL\/wp-content\/plugins\/gravityforms","number_formats":[],"spinnerUrl":"https:\/\/URL\/wp-content\/plugins\/gravityforms\/images\/spinner.gif"};jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(event, formId, currentPage){if(formId == 1) {} } );jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_conditional_logic', function(event, formId, fields, isInit){} );</script><script type='text/javascript'> jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [1, 1]) } ); </script>
```

I am skipping some sections to make it easier to read.

Here is the function:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x1 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["prenom"].value;
  var x2 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["nom"].value;
  var x3 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["adresse"].value;
  var x4 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["ville"].value;
  var x5 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["cp"].value;
  var x6 = document.forms["formulaireintervention"]["telephone"].value;
  var destruction = document.getElementsByName("destruction[]");
  var conditions = document.getElementsByName("conditions[]");
}
```

Here is the code from the valide-formulaire.php

```
<?php
// DEFINITION DES VARIABLES //
$dateref = date("YmdHis");
$reference             = "INT-$dateref";
$date                 = date("d/m/Y");
$heure                = date("H:i:s");
$ip                      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$classement                = "$dateref";
$prenom                = $_POST["prenom"];
$nom                  = $_POST["nom"];
$adresse               = $_POST["adresse"];
$ville                    = $_POST["ville"];
$cp                   = $_POST["cp"];
$telephone                 = $_POST["telephone"];
$adresseemail           = $_POST["adresseemail"];
$confirmationadresseemail  = $_POST["confirmationadresseemail"];
$nombredenids           = $_POST["nombredenids"];
$remarqueclient                = $_POST["remarqueclient"];
foreach($_POST['destruction']  as $nomd=>$valued)
{
   if($valued == "guepes"){$guepes = "1";}
   if($valued == "frelons"){$frelons = "1";}
   if($valued == "bourdons"){$bourdons = "1";}
   if($valued == "abeilles"){$abeilles = "1";}
}

foreach($_POST['urgente']  as $nomb=>$valueb)
{
   if($valueb == "oui"){$urgente = "1";}
}

foreach($_POST['facture']  as $nomc=>$valuec)
{
   if($valuec == "oui"){$envoifacture = "courrier";}
}

$premiernid = 70;
$surplus = 30;
$secondnid = 30;

if($nombredenids == "1"){
   if($urgente == "1") {
      $prix = 100;
   }
   if($urgente != "1") {
      $prix = 70;
   }
}

if($nombredenids > "1"){
   if($urgente == "1") {
      $restant = $nombredenids - "1";
      $prixnid = $secondnid * $restant;
      $prix = 70 + 30 + $prixnid;
   }
   if($urgente != "1") {
      $restant = $nombredenids - "1";
      $prixnid = $secondnid * $restant;
      $prix = 70 + $prixnid;
   }
}
   
$statut                   = "A";
$prestataire            = "0";
$password              = "";

// VERIFICATION //


if($prenom == "" || $nom == "" || $adresse == "" || $ville == "" || $cp == "" || $telephone == "")
{
   echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"0; URL = https:/URL/formulaire/?erreur=1\">";
   exit;
}

// INSCRIPTION DANS LA BDD //
include("config-bo.php");
   

$prenom = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $prenom);
$nom = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $nom);
$adresse = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $adresse);
$ville = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ville);
$remarqueclient = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $remarqueclient);

$requete91 = "INSERT INTO `intervention` (`id`, `reference`, `date`, `heure`, `ip`, `classement`, `prenom`, `nom`, `adresse`, `cp`, `ville`, `tva`, `telephone`, `email`, `nbnids`, `guepes`, `frelons`, `bourdons`, `abeilles`, `piece`, `facade`, `corniche`, `toiture`, `sol`, `arbre`, `hauteur`, `prix`, `statut`, `mdp`, `prestataire`, `urgente`, `rdvdate`, `rdvdate2`, `rdvheure`, `remarque`, `remarqueclient`, `facture`, `contrepartie_numero`, `contrepartie_presta`, `contrepartie_paye`, `envoifacture`, `raison`, `provenance`, `gestionnaire`, `contrepartie_recu`) VALUES (NULL, '$reference', '$date', '$heure', '$ip', '$classement', '$prenom', '$nom', '$adresse', '$cp', '$ville', '', '$telephone', '$adresseemail', '$nombredenids', '$guepes', '$frelons', '$bourdons', '$abeilles', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '$prix', '$statut', '$password', '$prestataire', '$urgente', '', '', '', '', '$remarqueclient', '', '', '', '', '$envoifacture', '', '', '', '');";
mysqli_query($link, $requete91);

$requete179 = "INSERT INTO `intervention_historique` (`ID`, `reference`, `statut`, `date`, `heure`, `remarque`, `user`) VALUES (NULL, '$reference', '$statut', '$date', '$heure', '', '');";
mysqli_query($link, $requete179);



if (mysqli_query($link, $requete179)) {

   echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"0; URL = https://URL.be/wp-content/themes/grafity/recap-formulaire-inter.php?reference=$reference&mdp=$password\">";
      exit;
 
     
     
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $requete179 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);   

?>
```

I am not sure where and if the webhooks are setup from here. If they are setup here, I would need to know where and if not, I would appreciate some help on how to setup new webhooks.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to look for some plugins that would help me setting up webhooks for free. I also looked at the code and tried to understand what information was sent with the $_POST.

Comment: so the form is being sent to a different website? and hosted on your own site?

Comment: Yes, we have different websites. We are sending the information from our various e-commerce to a central website.

Comment: you want to be very careful about checking where the content is coming from

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using Gravity Forms to build your forms. If so I would highly recommend to use one of the existing add-ons:

- [Webhooks](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/webhooks/)
- [Zapier](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/zapier/)

It is also possible to develop custom addon for Gravity Forms that would provide such functionality. You can find their developer documentation with examples [here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/developers/).

This is a correct way of triggering custom action after the form is submitted (see developer documentation for more details):

```
<?php
/**
 * After form is submitted, send data to 3rd party.
 *
 * @param array $entry
 * @param array $form
 * @return void
 */
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    $endpoint_url = 'https://example.com/rest/api/endpoint/';
    $body          = array(
        'firstname' => '', // extract data from $entry array.
        'lastname'  => '', // extract data from $entry array.
    );

    $response = wp_remote_post( $endpoint_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that the API was called on another page called recap-formulaire-inter.php
It is strange because the form is using a class from Gravity Form but the webhook was hardcoded. I am still testing but I am pretty sure I found it.